# How to make bold OpenGL ES 2.0 circle smooth properly using GL_LINE_LOOP

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm drawing circle using OpenGL ES 2.0 GL_LINE_LOOP and I want to make it bold properly, but when I use glLineWidth I get bad result where the outer side of the circle is broken, here is screenshot: 
[image]

How to make this circle like:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a quad or triangle strip with the vertices being on two circles apart by the desired width.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the resolution of the circle, it looks like you're using 12 segments, try it with 24 or 32.

Comment: Actually this resolution is enough for my purpose, the only problem is that outer side looks bad. It seems I should generate vertices for using triangle strip as suggested by @datenwolf ...

Comment: That's probably the better way to go about it, the only reason I suggest that is I once did something similar. With this approach I used code that would generate a circle given a radius and number of points by converting polar to cartesian coordinates. If you took a similar approach then it would be trivial to fix this problem by increasing the number of segments.

Comment: @DavidCarpenter: As soon as blending is used, using thick lines creates nasty artifacts. So that's another reason not to use it.